# How shall I understand this git rebase --onto example?

Tags: git

*Version Control with Git* has an example

> To transplant the P and Q commits on the feature branch from the maint to the master branch, issue the command:
>
> ```
>  $ git rebase --onto master maint^ feature
> ```

[image]

Does the following command also give the same result

```
git rebase --onto master maint feature
```

?

Why does the book use `maint^` instead of `maint`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm only going to give a short answer here due to lack of time:

> Does the following command also give the same result
>
> ```
> git rebase --onto master maint feature
> ```
>
> ?

**For this particular graph**, yes.  For (some) other graphs, no.  (Of course, for other graphs, they might have suggested other commands.)

> Why does the book use `maint^` instead of `maint`?

Not being the author, I can only guess.  This particular form of `git rebase` matches the first syntax in [the SYNOPSIS section of the `git rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_synopsis):

```
 git rebase [-i | --interactive] [<options>] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>]
         [<upstream> [<branch>]]
```

Here, they set *`newbase`*=`master`, *`upstream`*=`maint^`, and *`branch`*=`feature`.  So this will start by doing `git checkout feature`, then will enumerate commits in `maint^..HEAD` to find candidates for copying.  If you consult your graph, you will see that this is precisely commits `P` and `Q`: it starts at `Q`, walks back to `P`, walks from there to `Y`, and `Y` *is* `maint^`.

Using `git rebase --onto master maint feature`, Git would start at `Q`, walk back to `P`, walk back to `Y`, and still stop—because `maint` identifies `Z` and walking back from `Z` gets us to `Y`.  But that requires the extra step of walking back from `Z`.  Presumably the authors were unwilling to force the reader to take that extra step in the reader's head.

Comment: Shouldn't `--onto maint` be `--onto master maint`?

Comment: @A.H.: oops, yes.

Answer (score -1):

The three-argument form of git rebase –onto
Say there is a branch ‘topicA’ that diverges from master at some point:

A--B--C--D--E master

```
 F--G--H topicA
```

Let’s also say that someone else has branched from topicA to create topicB, and added more commits:

A--B--C--D--E master

```
 F--G--H topicA

         I--J--K--L--M topicB
```

This is an example of a real-world case I came across, where topicA had only a couple very large commits that were hard to digest and could have been split into many smaller commits. topicB was created as a continuation of the work done on topicA.

I checked out my own local copy of topicA, and through much interactive rebasing and prodigious use of git add -e, I was able to split topicA into smaller commits, making topicC:

A--B--C--D--E master
   |
   | F--G--H topicA
   |
   |         I--J--K--L--M topicB
   |
   N--O--P--Q--R--S--T--U--V--W topicC

I talked with the person that made topicA and we agreed that my branch topicC should take the place of topicA. But what to do about the work that was done on topicB?

The operation that we wanted to do is: make topicC the new base of topicB, cutting it at the point topicB diverged from topicA, which looks like:

A--B--C--D--E master
   |
   | F--G--H topicA
   |
   |         I--J--K--L--M topicB

```
 N--O--P--Q--R--S--T--U--V--W--I'--J'--K'--L'--M' topicC
```

The five commits from topicB (I through M), get played on top of topicC, starting from where topicB diverged from topicA, to create I’, J’, K’, L’, and M’.

The command to do this is:

```
git rebase --onto topicC topicA topicB
```

Where topicC is the newbase, topicA is the oldbase, and topicB is the reference for what HEAD of topicC will become.

So your answer is, yes it can be used without the ^

The significance of ^ is :

HEAD^ means the first parent of the tip of the current branch.

Remember that git commits can have more than one parent. HEAD^ is short for HEAD^1, and you can also address HEAD^2 and so on as appropriate.

You can get to parents of any commit, not just HEAD. You can also move back through generations: for example, master~2 means the grandparent of the tip of the master branch, favoring the first parent in cases of ambiguity. These specifiers can be chained arbitrarily , e.g., topic~3^2.